# How to interact using Selenium with already opened browser?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-remote-debugging

Till a few days back what was working perfectly:

Open browser with:
`"C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222`

then in python I check the response status code (should be `200`) using `GET` request to `http://localhost:9222`.

then attach selenium:

```
options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe"
options.add_argument("disable-popup-blocking")
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress",
        socket.gethostbyname("localhost:9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options = options)
```

However, this setup is not working anymore, as nothing can be accessed through `http://localhost:9222` now with new updates.

Any idea how to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it's working:

Run the below command in command prompt:

```
"C:\\Program Files\\BraveSoftware\\Brave-Browser\\Application\\brave.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\\Temp\\BraveData"
```

Brave browser will be launched, then use the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.core.utils import ChromeType

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.BRAVE).install()), options = options)
```